# How to get JSON object key value pairs to be on its own line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object, jsx

I have a json object stored inside as an object called

> job

It renders as

```
{"amount": " 12185","job": "GAPA","month": "JANUARY","year": "2010"}
```

I would like to know how to get it to look like this in jsx/javascript

```
{
    "amount": " 12185",
    "job": "GAPA",
    "month": "JANUARY",
    "year": "2010"
  }
```

I was looking around and couldnt find anyone asking the same question

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myJSObject, null, 4)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your ide you are using . If you're using VS code you can install prettier / eslint extention to format it to ES6 automatically on save